# Using JAX-RS (RESTEasy) with CDI (Weld) in Tomcat 7

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, cdi, tomcat7, jboss-weld

In a JSF 2.0 application (running on Tomcat 7 and using weld 1.1.1.Final), I want to propose my user to download some binary files (.doc, .pdf etc).

In order to fulfil that need, I want to use a JAX-RS (RESTEasy 2.2.0.Final) resource bean (annotated with `@Path`). The problem is that inside that bean, I want to call a service from a field annotated with `@Inject` annotation.

Actually, like [a weld user trying a similar thing](http://seamframework.org/Community/WELDAndInjectingFromExternalJars) I've got a `NullPointerException` : Weld doesn't inject me my service.

So I read [a post on JBoss community wiki talking about how to integrate RESTEasy with CDI](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RESTEasy-CDIIntegration) so I've made my maven war project depend on `org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-cdi` and here is my `web.xml` :

```xml
<!-- Weld -->
<resource-env-ref>
    <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ConversationPropagationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ConversationPropagationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Resteasy -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.injector.factory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The problem now is that when my application bootstraps, I've got that exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate InjectorFactory implementation.
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.lookupBeanManager(CdiInjectorFactory.java:116)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.<init>(CdiInjectorFactory.java:41)
...
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:133)
```

And when I remove the `resteasy.injector.factory` context-param, I've got an `NPE` when trying to get my service from the field variable annotated with `@Inject` ...

Does anybody knows how to configure RESTEasy beans to be managed by Weld (and make possible injection in JAX-RS resources) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in RESTEasy trunk. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-558 for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you know how can I test it with Maven ?

Comment: Wait for RESTEasy 2.1.1 which should be out on 2011-06-23

Answer (score 0):

If you have the chance and the effort is reasonable: Try the same scenario wiht JBoss AS 6. If that works, you'll probably nailed down a configuration issues. If it fails with a similiar (or equal) exception, you know that it's Weld to blame ;-)

Both outcomes should at least give you a direction where to look next...