# Keycloak secure Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I am testing the security of a web application spring boot with keycloak, I added all the necessary dependencies, but I have a problem while lacerating the application.

I use :
spring boot 2.2.0.M3
Java 11

I include:
keycloak-spring-boot-starter and keycloak-adapter-bom

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>gn.traore</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-spring-boot-keycloak</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>demo-spring-boot-keycloak</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot with Keycloak</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak.bom/keycloak-adapter-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

It's show me this error message:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dupl
icate context initialization parameter [keycloak.config.resolver]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157)
 ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M2.
jar:5.2.0.M2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~
[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:404) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1275) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1263) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at gn.traore.DemoSpringBootKeycloakApplication.main(DemoSpringBootKeycloakApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate context initialization parameter [keycloak.config.resolver]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addParameter(StandardContext.java:3111) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakBaseSpringBootConfiguration$KeycloakBaseTomcatContextCustomizer.customize(KeycloakBaseSpringB
ootConfiguration.java:271) ~[keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configureContext(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:377) ~[
spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:234) ~[sp
ring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:183) ~[spri
ng-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.jav
a:181) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
 ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Any chance it's getting included twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068148/resteasy-cdi-getting-duplicate-context-initialization-parameter-resteasy-inje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in spring-boot that webserver customizers are called twice. Because that bug keycloak is initialized twice. It's solved in spring-boot 2.2.0.M5. So upgrading spring-boot will solve the issue.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17264

Answer (score -1):

You can exclude `KeycloakAutoConfiguration` class by adding

```
@SpringBootApplication( exclude = { KeycloakAutoConfiguration.class } )
```

annotation to your main application class.

Comment: I've exclude KeycloakAutoConfiguration and it work now...thank you !

Comment: Not the correct or best answer because this is only a workaround where you disable sprintboot autoconfig and you have to configure it all by hand. Gives also problems with using the KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.